# how to load the resources from the nested jar files resources

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

i have one jar file inside it there is lib folder which contain all the jar files which we mentaion in the pom file.

here the question is : how is read the all the external jar (pom file jars) files resources.
example : example.jar has dependies in lib folder **file1.jar** & **file2.jar** i want to read the resource of both file1.jar and file2.jar

how JVM loads the all the resources?

Comment: using **getResourceAsStream()** we can achive but inside jar resources not able to load.

Comment: Assuming the ClassLoader of those jar files is accessiboe, you can use that to gain acccess to the resources.

Comment: You should not be placing a .jar file inside another .jar file.  There are ways to assemble an application comprised of multiple .jar files, so that all of them are on the classpath or module path.  For example, you can use the standard [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jlink.html) tool, or you can just bundle a shell script and .bat file alongside the .jar files.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very unusual situation, maybe much better approach which is usually used is "flatterning" the jars, so you won't have dependent jars in some folder inside an "outer" jar, but instead all packages from dependent jars will become packages of the outer jar residing next to your own code that probably is in the outer jar anyway.

Maven has [shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) for this, and this is usually the way to go.

One noticeable exception is a spring boot applications packaged as JARs that work just like you've said (they put dependent jars into `BOOT-INF/lib` library, so technically its jars inside jar).
They have their own reasons to work like this which are way beyond the scope of this question, but the relevant point is that they had to create a special class loader that would handle this situation. Java out of the box can read classes from filesystem or from regular jar, but in theory java application can read the binary code from any place (Remote Filesystem, Database, Jar inside Jar whatever) as long as you implement the class loader that can find and load the resources from there.

In general I would recommend not to mess with Class Loaders which are pretty advanced concepts unless you really know what you're doing. Most of java programmers do not really create their own class loaders.

Answer (score -3):

venkateswararao yeluru please follow below code to read data from jar file:

```
public class FirstExample {
            // JDBC driver name and database URL
            static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";***`
            strong text`***
            static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";

            // Database credentials
            static final String USER = "username";
            static final String PASS = "password";

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Connection conn = null;
                Statement stmt = null;
                try {
                    // STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
                    Underclassmen("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                    // STEP 3: Open a connection
                    System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

                    // STEP 4: Execute a query
                    System.out.println("Creating statement...");
                    stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    String sql;
                    sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM Employees";
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                    // STEP 5: Extract data from result set
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        // Retrieve by column name
                        int id = rs.getInt("id");
                        int age = rs.getInt("age");
                        String first = rs.getString("first");
                        String last = rs.getString("last");

                        // Display values
                        System.out.print("ID: " + id);
                        System.out.print(", Age: " + age);
                        System.out.print(", First: " + first);
                        System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
                    }
                    // STEP 6: Clean-up environment
                    rs.close();
                    stmt.close();
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    // Handle errors for JDBC
                    se.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Handle errors for Class.forName
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    // finally block used to close resources
                    try {
                        if (stmt != null)
                            stmt.close();
                    } catch (SQLException se2) {
                    } // nothing we can do
                    try {
                        if (conn != null)
                            conn.close();
                    } catch (SQLException se) {
                        se.printStackTrace();
                    } // end finally try
                } // end try
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            }// end main
        }// end FirstExample
```

Comment: you posted read the data from database..it's not related to my problem.

Comment: @Zoe this is simply the JDBC example boilerplate. There are thousands upon thousands of projects that use it, see https://github.com/search?l=&q=STEP+2%3A+Register+JDBC+driver&type=Code. It’s not clear who first wrote it but https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-create-database.htm would be a better source. I hardly call this plagiarism if a favourite IDE hands it to you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This question has nothing to do with JDBC, I don't understand how this is even remotly an answer to this question.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn that’s a different issue altogether. Feel free to vote it down.